# Hotkey to run macro when viewing the email

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I have a macro that sends a reply to email selected in the inbox. I assigned it to the Quick Access Toolbar and run it by pressing alt+1.

The hotkey does not work when I view the email itself (I sometimes open it from within a task). In email view I can go to the macros ribbon and run it manually and it works, but I can't find the way to run it with the hotkey. Any suggestions?

I need to view email and decide if I run the reply macro or not, so a solution to run it on open action won't work.

edit: solution i comments

Comment: There is a separate Quick Access Toolbar for open mailitems. If the 1 is over the Save icon, you are currently saving with Alt+1. If the code can process ActiveInspector.CurrentItem then you can add the macro.

Comment: omg, so simple! thank you! I really need to improve my google search skills. Feel free to post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a separate Quick Access Toolbar for open mailitems. If the 1 is over the Save icon, you are currently saving with Alt+1.

If the code can process ActiveInspector.CurrentItem then you can add the macro.